# Form submit just refreshes screen with no changes made

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have a simple little script that will allow a non-admin club member to edit some text on a website.  I have it working just fine outside of the CMS that I am using.  Due to the inherent lack of security I am now trying to move it into a folder in the CMS structure.  I don't think my question really centers around the fact that a CMS is involved just yet...right now I'm just trying to understand why the **unaltered** script does not work just moving it to a different folder.

The actual text file to be edited will remain outside the CMS folder structure...there's nothing inherently wrong in anyone seeing this file.  It's just the edit routine that needs protection...but I'm just trying to get it to work now that I've moved it.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$fn = "http://www.mydomain.org/Public_Files/folder/FileToEdit.txt";
if (isset($_POST['content']))
{
    $content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);
    $fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
    fputs($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
    <textarea rows="40" cols="40" name="content"><?php readfile($fn); ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes"> 
</form>
```

As you can see...it's a pretty simple script...but wide open!  I understand that...will address that as my next step.

**Here is my problem**...this code correctly brings up the file to edit and lets you make a change and submit...but it just refreshes the screen and shows the original un-altered file again.

This script lives at: http://www.mydomain.org/cmsfolder/folder/subfolder/edittext.php

As best I can tell, only the $fn variable needs to change to accurately point to the file to edit.
When the edit script lived in the same folder as the text file (outside the CMS) all was good.  When it was in this folder the $fn variable was **$fn = "FileToEdit.txt";**  I am fairly certain that there are no permissions applied by the CMS that are affecting this.

What am I missing in just getting it to work from the moved folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable $fn should be the path for the file on the filesystem, like:

```
$fn = "FileToEdit.txt";
$fn = "../FileToEdit.txt";
$fn = "data/FileToEdit.txt";
$fn = "/var/www/data/FileToEdit.txt";
```

and so on...

Comment: So...you're saying it should not be in the form of a URL? Is that why it works when it is in the same folder referenced only as $fn = "FileToEdit.txt"; ?